# Check if a file exists and (only if it does) open another file (or folder) or run an application

Tags: vbscript

I am looking for a vb script that checks if (at a specific path) a file exists and (only if it does exist) then opens another file (or folder) or runs an application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Set fileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fileSystemObject.FileExists(file) Then

    'Do what you need

End If
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
Set fileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fileSystemObject.FileExists("ok.txt") Then
  CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "nice.txt"
End If
```

It checks if the `ok.txt` file exists (in the same folder as the vbs) and then executes the `nice.txt` file.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The above script works if *both* files (ok.txt & nice.txt) are in the same folder as the vbs but what if they are located under different paths (on the same local disk)? I noticed that adding the complete path does not work :(

Comment: If you put the full file path it should work. Read this, see if it helps: http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/14048.asp

Comment: Just adding the path does not work but I found out that using the DOS path solves the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

In this way (with the DOS path) the script works:

```
Set fileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fileSystemObject.FileExists("D:\MYSCRE~1\ok.txt") Then
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "D:\MYSCRE~1\nice.txt"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Function Main()

Dim fso 

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not(fso.FileExists(drive_name:\folder\filename.txt")) Then

       Main = 1/0

End If
```